# System.IO.FileNotFoundException - the system could not find the path specified?

Tags: c#, path

I'm currently having a bit of an issue regarding the project finding a specified configuration file. I figured the best way to run configuration in one of our .NET Core Console projects would be via a `appsettings.json` file, instead of making it more complicated than it has to be right now.

That said, when running the project on it's own, it seems to work perfectly fine. But when referencing it from another project in the solution and running it that way, it doesn't seem to find the (absolute) path specified, even though it targets that exact file when copy & pasted into Windows Explorer.

This image displays the code where we are calling it, and like previously said, copy-pasting it into a explorer takes us exactly where it should

[image]

Another day, another issue I can't quite wrap my head around why it would be happening. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I was stuck with same problem, I just replaced all \ to `/` and it worked. And why don't you use relative file path? It's more robust.

Comment: @MyBug18 Pretty sure I tried that but can test it again later! Will be using relative paths down the line but want/need something that'll just work for now.

Comment: @MyBug18 Nope, same issue! Works when running the project by itself but when referenced by another project it throws the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by running `Update-Package -Reinstall` in the NPM console and removing the `<runtime></runtime>` tags in the `Web.config` file

Answer (score 0):

If you use `appsettings.json` which is located in default location (project root directory) I would suggest going for:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

Configuration = builder.Build();
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why it wouldn't find the file using an ABSOLUTE path though, does it?